# What is the smallest planar cubic bipartite asymmetric graph?

Tags: graph-theory, bipartite-graphs, symmetry

["According to a strengthened version of Frucht's theorem, there are infinitely many asymmetric cubic graphs."](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymmetric_graph#Examples)
If there are any, what is the smallest cubic bipartite asymmetric graph?

Kind of a bipartite version of Frucht's graph. If there are none, why's that?

**EDIT:** The graph doesn't necessarily need to be planar, but $3$-edge-colorable...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a combination of the [geng](http://pallini.di.uniroma1.it/) and [IGraph/M](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM) tools, I find none with less than 18 vertices. With 18 vertices, there are 13 of them:

Mathematica code:

```
Needs["IGraphM`"]
grs = Select[
  IGImport["!geng -d3 -D3 -b 18", "Nauty"],
  IGBlissAutomorphismGroup[#] === PermutationGroup[{}] &
]
```

[image]

In graph6 notation (so that you can compute with them e.g. in Sage),

```
Q??????wE_P_Y?F?AW@D??w?D_?
Q??????wE_P_Y?E_CW?F?@W?S_?
Q??????wE_P_Y?B_CW?d?CW?D_?
Q??????wE_P_W_IO@o?d?CW?D_?
Q??????wE_P_Q_J?EG?d??w?D_?
Q??????wE_P_Q_B_Cg@`?CW?B_?
Q??????wE_P_Q_IOCo?h?CW?B_?
Q??????wE_P_Q_IOEG?h?@g?B_?
Q??????wE_P_Q_IOCc?k?CW?B_?
Q??????wE_P_Q_BOCo?F?CW?o_?
Q??????wE_P_Q_BOCc@a?Cg?B_?
Q??????wCoOo[?R?AW?L?GW?H_?
Q??????wCoOoSOPGAW?L?IG?h??
```

The smallest ones that are also planar have 22 vertices:

```
grs = Select[IGImport["!/opt/local/bin/geng -d3 -D3 -b 22", "Nauty"], 
   IGBlissAutomorphismGroup[#] === PermutationGroup[{}] &];

Select[grs, IGPlanarQ]
```

[image]

```
U?????????[?s?b?M?@S?BO?D_?`_?@o?AW??q??
U?????????[?s?b?M?@S?BO?Co?d??@o?BG??U??
```

Comment: Disclosure: I am the author of IGraph/M and this was not meant as advertisement for the tool. I was just interested in the topic.

Comment: Very nice, can you further restrict the length of the "faces" to 6 and 8?

Comment: @draks... Do you want it to be planar? If not, what do you mean by faces?

Comment: living on a orientable surface (like a double-torus) would also do. But maybe restricting the length of the smallest cycles would also do...

Comment: @draks... The problem is that there is no unique embedding, and each possible embedding will have faces of different size. The length of the shortest cycle is the girth, it can be computed with `IGGirth` in IGraph/M. The 22-vertex graphs I show above have girth 4. You want girth 6? I'm not sure if we can go to 24 vertices with these tools ... too many graphs. 26 is certainly infeasible. Maybe with some programming directly in C, using nauty ...

Comment: Yes girth 6 would be one thing. My current main interest is on bicubic graphs that live on surfaces with genus -2 (double tori) and are composed of hexagons and octagons only. If you or your tool could help here, that would be great...

Answer (score 3):

There are 85 cubic graphs on 12 vertices and five of them are asymmetric, and all five are 3-edge colourable. No cubic graph on 10 vertices is asymmetric; I did not bother to check the graphs on eight vertices, because my recollection was that the smallest asymmetric regular graphs are on 12 vertices. (All computations in sage.)

Comment: How many of them are bipartite?

Comment: [Here](http://www.mathe2.uni-bayreuth.de/markus/reggraphs.html#BIPARTITE) they say that $5$ of them are bipartite. Can you confirm that?

Comment: oh and [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BicubicGraph.html) they are shown...only "$12$-cubic graph 66" looks asymmetric to me!